# I am looking for a reverse API tool

Tags: phonetics, ipa

I'm looking for a tool for write the sound of the word (phonetic) and have all the words that have that sound.

It's very usefull when people don't use the good sounds or to know what a native speaker is going to heard if you don't speak well.

For example, if a French speaker says : "Ghost Love" with the pronunciation /gost/ /love/. Does the sound /gost/ mean someting in English?

French people say : Star /wars/ instead of star /wɔrz/. Does /wars/ mean something? or /irɔn/ instead of /ˈaɪərn/, etc.

Thank you.

EDIT :

I found out that website : http://www.phonemicchart.com/transcribe/ The problem I have is that the web site uses British phonemes. So, it's almost good : )

Comment: There are several such databases. The one I have used is http://www.benbriedis.com/phonetic/search.php: it's not perfect, but it's online and free. To search effectively, you need to use the key to determine which phoneme you want to represent from the recorded accent.

Comment: Thank you but very difficult to use. I can't find out results with my examples.

Comment: So are you looking for a programmatic API or do you just want a reverse phonetic dictionary to look up as a person some one-offs when you're curious? If the former you probably want to ask on Stack Overflow; if the latter, this should be moved to ELU.meta (just a local policy about resource requests).

Comment: I just want a reverse phonetic dictionary. I finally managed to use benbriedis.com, even though it's not easy.